# How to do mathematical operations in database query?

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a table in my database with columns such as `id`, `user_id`, `value`. `value` can be only 0, 1 and 2. Every users can have multiple rows.

I want to  list all people in this table, ordered by a proportion. `proportion` is defined as

```
(rows count value = 1) / (sum of value = 1 and value = 2)
```

For example, if a user have 15 row where `value` equals `1` and 20 rows where `value` equal 2 the proportion will be `15 / (15+20)`.

How do I write a query to get that value?

Comment: Just getting results group by user and value. 
$basarili = \DB::table('kuponlar')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'kuponlar.user_id')
            ->select(\DB::raw('count(*) as tutansayisi, users.username, users.id', 'kuponlar.value'))
            ->groupBy('kuponlar.user_id', 'kuponlar.value')
            ->orderBy('tutansayisi', 'desc')
            ->get();

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on exactly what type of database you have (e.g. MySQL, MSSQL, etc).  You can do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT main.user_id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM user_table sub 
    WHERE main.user_id = total.user_id
    AND total.value != 0
  ) AS total,
  (COUNT(*)/total) AS ratio
FROM user_table main
WHERE main.value=1
GROUP BY main.user_id
ORDER BY ratio
```

This basically gets you the total in a subquery and then uses it to calculate the ratio.  As I mentioned, the exact syntax of this query will vary slightly depending on your database technology.